# Expresso Store: Creating orders on behalf of other members

Tags: expresso-store

My client needs to be able to invoice customers, have them pay online, and then see payment history. I was planning on having the client enter an unpaid order and assign it to the right member. Then the member could login in, see unpaid orders, and pay them. I'm not very familiar with store. Do you see any major problems with this approach? Is this even doable out of the box? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That would be possible with Store, there are a couple of ways to achieve it.

The easiest way is if your client just logs in as the member in question to place the order. This would be possible using EE's "login as member" function in the control panel.

The other approach would be if they create the order under their own account, then assign the order to the other member. Store doesn't have the ability to create new orders from within the control panel, but this would be easy for them to do on the front end of your website. You can use the "Manual" payment gateway to allow the order to be completed without payment. Then, to assign the order to the new member you would just need to write a simple plugin/extension which changes the `member_id` in the `exp_store_orders` database table to the correct customer.

Finally, you can allow the customer to log in and view their orders, then use the [payment tag](https://exp-resso.com/docs/payment_tag.html) to let them pay for the existing order.